# Combine multiple MTKView/CAMetalLayer display

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I am using multiple MTKViews to display different contents on the screen along with normal UIView's (for displaying UI). I want to synchronize presentation of these MTKViews together with the same clock. Is there a way to synchronize the presentation of these MTKViews? In principal, I can combine the layouts of these views to a single MTKView but that would kill modularity of the code and not sure if I would achieve anything on the performance with so much of overwork.

Comment: Synchronize them how, exactly? Do you want them to have a fixed frame rate (e.g. 60 fps)? Do you want them to all draw together but at a variable frame rate (they all render as soon as the slowest is finished)? Or do you have some other system in mind, like if one of them is slow enough, it skips frames that the others might draw, but the ones that do draw do so together and when the slow one can, it participates in that lockstep?

Comment: I want to draw them at a fixed frame rate, all together with the same clock in a lockstep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach that should work in most cases would be to compute the time at which you'd like the frame to draw and use the `present(_:atTime:)` method of `MTLCommandBuffer` instead of the `present(_:)` method.

---

To exert greater control, it helps to understand what a command buffer's `present...` methods do and don't do. They do **not** encode any command into the buffer. As documented, they basically just add a scheduled handler to themselves that calls `present` on the drawable.

If you're careful about it, you can arrange to present the drawable in a way that doesn't much involve the command buffer.

But, does the command buffer using a *scheduled* handler make sense? Shouldn't it use a *completed* handler? After all, you want to display the completed rendering, right?

Well, drawables are smart about presenting themselves. The `present` method doesn't present immediately. A drawable tracks which scheduled commands might render or write to its texture. When `present` is called, that arranges for the drawable to draw itself on the screen as soon as possible *after all such commands have completed*. (Note that this does not imply that the command buffer itself has completed. There may be additional commands that don't involve the drawable's texture that aren't yet completed.)

This provides both challenges and opportunities for syncing the presentation of multiple drawables. The challenge is that, while you can control when you call `present` on each drawable, that doesn't necessarily sync their actual display, because each will display as soon it can after `present` is called and all commands involving its texture are completed, and that last part can occur at different times for different drawables.

One possible approach to solving this is to add a presented handler to the master drawable. The handler would call `present` on the other 3 drawables. After all of the command buffers are scheduled, call `present` on the master drawable. You can use a dispatch group to determine when all of the command buffers are scheduled. Enter the group once for each command buffer and add a scheduled handler to each that leaves the group. Then set a notify block on the group that does the master present. This technique probably won't achieve perfect synchronization because there's latency between when the master drawable has actually presented and when the presented handler is called, and then latency in presenting the other drawables.

Another possible approach is to set the `presentsWithTransaction` property of all of your `CAMetalLayer`s to true. Then, when it's time to present, call `waitUntilScheduled` on each command buffer followed by `present` on each drawable. (Do not use a `present...` method of the command buffer.) This will guarantee that all of the drawables will present during the same Core Animation transaction – that is, synchronized.

Comment: But can the single MTLCommandBuffer be used to present 4 different MTKViews/CAMetalLayer?

Comment: It can, but my suggestion doesn't have anything to do with that. You could use four different command buffers and have them all present at the same time. The point is the API gives you control over when a drawable is presented, which is a tool you can use to synchronize them.

Comment: Interesting, but present(_:atTime:) has an issue. I would like to synchronize the remaining 3 views with the presentation of master(which is video preview). I know I can delay video preview by 30 milliseconds and then show everything using _atTime: ,which wouldn't be noticeable, but is it possible in principle to sync the remaining views with one view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use presentsWithTransaction

1. Set presentsWithTransaction = true in MTKView
2. Change commandBuffer commit style

   ```
    public func draw(in view: MTKView) {

    ...

    commandBuffer?.commit()
    commandBuffer?.waitUntilScheduled()
    view.currentDrawable?.present() }
   ```

Now all the metal views will be displayed synchronously.
It works for me.